# How does VS Code for the Web or Code Server Web work?

Tags: web, visual-studio-code, server

How does VS Code for the Web or Code Server Web work？
Specifically, how does the front end that on the chrome (browser) communicate with the back end (server)?

For example, I know that when we deploy vscode on the docker, the lsp client is work on the server side. How does it transmit data to the browser?

Comment: Websockets? Did you open your browser's devtools and look what's sent/received?

Comment: I guess is websocket，But I wonder how the source code of the vscode implement it. there is just one implement of that, but it both support vscode run on windows and code server run on the web